# Svmono hack. How to change font size in Springer Verlag Class?

Tags: fontsize, templates, class-options

I am writing my Ph.D. thesis with `svmono` class of Springer-Verlag, but the default size is `10pt` and seems to me too difficult to read. I would like to change to `11pt` or `12pt`. This two option are blocked, so for first i have commented the two line

```
%\DeclareOption{11pt}{\OptionNotUsed}

%\DeclareOption{12pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
```

but seems that this is not sufficient. What i have to do? Here is the
[class definition](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/rrtex/styles/svmono.cls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the two line after the one you mentioned:

```
\def\@rticle@options{10pt,twoside}
% fleqn
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\def\@rticle@options{10pt,twoside,fleqn}%
```

Replace the "10pt". But don't change the original class but save the file under a new name.

Edit: svmono not only loads article.cls but also change some font sizes later on. Search the line

```
% fonts, sizes, and the like
```

and correct the definitions which follows. You can use the values used in size12.clo as template/inspiration.

Btw: This is a very special class. Why are you using it instead of a class e.g. from the KOMA bundle or memoir?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: i used this class for my degree. Is a sort continuity with the past .)